# Timezone is not changing in the routed function

Tags: php, symfony4, fosrestbundle

I have this symfony4.3 (latest) PHP application and I am trying to insert to the database using Doctrine ORM and I need to insert the time which this query happened but I need a specific timezone and the timezone is not changing using either the date_default_timezone_set() or setTimeZone()

```
$entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
date_default_timezone_set("America/Bahia");
$customer = new Customer();
$customer->setName($name);
$customer->setPhone($phone);
$dt = new \DateTimeImmutable(date('m/d/y G:i:s'));
$tz = new \DateTimeZone("America/Bahia");
$dt->setTimezone($tz);
$customer->setCreated($dt);
```

I expect the timezone in the created cell to be changed to America/Bahia

Actual Output :
Europe/Helsinki
which is the timezone of the server

Comment: Where did you check that? On reading the value from the database? Which type has your column?

Comment: My column has type DateTime and yes from my reactjs app so from DB

Comment: In reactjs I get the JSON from symfony and value is under created.timezone

Comment: And what's the **exact** value that is stored in the database? How **exactly** did you check that the value `Europe/Helsinki` was stored in the DB?

Comment: I just checked in the database and the latest output is 2019-04-12 11:18:59 , which I think actually has the new timezone! I dont know why created.timezone still says Helsinki though

Comment: So, obviously that string does not contain any information about the timezone. Is that timezone always the same throughout your application? Then you should set it in `php.ini`

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction @NicoHaase I figured it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out it was changing the timezone correctly and storing the right value in the database,
But the problem was that everytime you try to access the timezone from the datetime object after getting it from the database it will only show the timezone of the php.ini file or something and not the timezone you actually used to store the datetime with!.
I think if we actually need the exact timezone used during insert or update we need to store it in a different column.